# I'm getting Unexpected exception caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException, msg=null in ADF Application

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I've observed groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException in one of the screen in application built on ADF. I'm deploying the application in localhost. With same source code, screens are working fine for my peers whereas I'm facing above mentioned issue while opening Add/Edit Screens and all the fields in the form is disabled. So, I'm suspecting that issue is with either Weblogic or JDeveloper.

Logs:

```
####<15 Nov, 2023 3:28:24,533 PM IST> <Warning> <org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXFacesBeanImpl> <xxxxxx-xxxxxx> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '35' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <DEMOSUPR> <> <84b10605-3bbb-49ac-b2ac-9ae3d812d768-00000172> <1700042304533> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000000> <Invalid value mutation during decode or encode: View=/pages/xxxxxx.jsf Component=pt1:pt_np1 attr=value EL=#{viewScope.tabContext.tabMenuModel} old=org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.model.ChildPropertyMenuModel@24fb2235 new=org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.model.ChildPropertyMenuModel@176584a3>
####<15 Nov, 2023 3:28:24,665 PM IST> <Warning> <oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer> <xxxxxx-xxxxxxx> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '35' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <DEMOSUPR> <> <84b10605-3bbb-49ac-b2ac-9ae3d812d768-00000172> <1700042304665> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <ADF_FACES-30214> <The setting to enable version display will be ignored because the application is running in production mode.>
```

**Operating System** : Windows 11

**JDK Version** :  jdk1.8.0_341

**JDeveloper Version**: Studio Edition Version 12.2.1.4.0 ~ Build JDEVADF_PT.12.2.1.4.0_GENERIC_190911.2248.S

**Weblogic Version**: WebLogic Server Version 12.2.1.4.0 (Using Embedded weblogic)

Please let me know if I can get some inputs on this.

I have tried reinstalling JDeveloper and then tried navigating to Add/Edit Screens. But still issue was persistently occuring. I have also deleted temporary folder of JDeveloper located in C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper and then tried to deploy the application.